# How to delete a child node with unique key in firebase Realtime database in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I want to remove child which having unique number as a key. And I have created the unique number using .push(). My database structure is like this-

```js
{
    mobile{
     +917654387629{
       -NE0wCPZV-tRi84DHFxs:"gc27dghd07671a91e3" //-NE0wCPZV-tRi84DHFxs(unique key),gc27dghd07671a91e3 (value of unique key)
       -NE5-b0YTUVPZ7tad9Dz:"gc2ie23c636gde57a6" //-NE5-b0YTUVPZ7tad9Dz(unique key)

     }
   }
}
```

I am getting mobile number and value from the user and I want to match the number and the value, if I get that given value under the given mobile number then I want to delete that unique key and its value only. I have tried this code

```js
firebase.database().ref('mobile/'+localStorage.getItem('OldPhoneNo')).once('value',snapshot =>{
  snapshot.forEach((data) => {
      console.log(data.val())
      console.log(data.key)
      if(data.val() == qrCodeMessage){
        firebase.database().ref('mobile/'+localStorage.getItem('OldPhoneNo')+(data.val())).remove();           
      }
  })
});
```

but I am unable to understand how to delete the value of unique key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definitely seems wrong:

```
firebase.database().ref('mobile/'+localStorage.getItem('OldPhoneNo')+(data.val())).remove();
```

Two things:

1. To remove a node, you need to specify its **key** and not its value.
2. You need a `/` between all keys in the path, and you're missing one after `OldPhoneNo`.

So:

```
firebase.database().ref('mobile/'+localStorage.getItem('OldPhoneNo')+'/'+data.key).remove();
```